# Can you build a Python built in 3.9 to target python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, pypi

I maintain a python module that is built with 3.9 syntax, but it is apart from that not dependant on anything else in python 3.8 or 3.9. None of its dependencies seem to be tied to anything higher than 3.7.

When building/packaging this and publishing it on PyPi repository, can I make the build compatible with 3.7?

Comment: Remove any syntax which isn't compatible with 3.7…?!

Comment: So you're asking whether there is a tool that would convert incompatible 3.9 syntax elements into equivalent 3.7 constructs?  I'm unsure whether such a thing exists.  It seems unlikely.  But even if it *did* exist, why would using it be better than maintaining your code in 3.7-compatible syntax in the first place?

Comment: I wonder if there is something - like a dependency - you can use to keep your 3.9 syntax and still target 3.7.

The reason is that the syntax used would require a lot of re-working the code when the need for the module to be run in 3.7 will go away.